# Absolute position after data on same line

Tags: javascript, css, tooltip

I'm trying to add custom tool tips after input boxes and I have it working fine, except for when I submit the form and the errors show. For some reason, the tool tip blocks the error text. It's just odd and I've been wracking my brain too long now to figure it out.

[Here](http://www.marianoagency.com/certificate) is the page in question.

I only have the tool tips on the first four inputs. They work fine until you submit the form showing the errors. Click submit to see the odd behavior.

Ultimately the goal would be to the tool tip appear over the error text and then disappear and show the error text when you tab back/click to another field.

Any ideas?

```
function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    } else {
        window.onload = function() {
            oldonload();
            func();
        }
    }
}

function prepareInputsForHints() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        // test to see if the hint span exists first
        if (inputs[i].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]) {
            // the span exists!  on focus, show the hint
            inputs[i].onfocus = function() {
                this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.display = "inline";
            }
            // when the cursor moves away from the field, hide the hint
            inputs[i].onblur = function() {
                this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
    // repeat the same tests as above for selects
    var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for (var k = 0; k < selects.length; k++) {
        if (selects[k].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]) {
            selects[k].onfocus = function() {
                this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.display = "inline";
            }
            selects[k].onblur = function() {
                this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
addLoadEvent(prepareInputsForHints);
```

Here is the CSS for the `error` class and `hint` class:

```
.error {
    margin-left:5px;
    font-size:.75em;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:80px;
    color:#FF0000;
}

.hint {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:650px;
    width:200px;
    margin-top:-4px;
    border:1px solid #c93;
    padding:1.5px 10px 1.5px 10px;
        /* to fix IE6, I can't just declare a background-color,
        I must do a bg image, too!  So I'm duplicating the pointer.gif
        image, and positioning it so that it doesn't show up
        within the box */
    background:#ffc url(pointer.gif) no-repeat -10px 5px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

/* The pointer image is added by using another span */
.hint .hint-pointer {
    position:absolute;
    left:-10px;
    top:-1px;
    width:10px;
    height:19px;
    background: url(/_images/pointer.gif) left top no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest including your javascript functions for showing and hiding tool tips and error messages with this question. My first thought however would be that you are targeting the first `<span>` tag you come across rather than selecting the tag by class name.

Comment: I am assuming your are using javascript or a javascript framework to make this happen. Would it be possible to see that javascript code? It looks like maybe something is crossed up, essential you should be able to have a div containing the error and another containing the tooltip. From there you should be able to have them set to display:none; by default and then show them on blur.

Comment: Added code but it shouldn't be that. It's the CSS that is affecting it's display, though I could be wrong.

Comment: Maybe I'll try making error a div instead of span a class ("error") and see if that works better.

Comment: Right off the bat I notice you're missing a semicolon for your `window.onload` function.

Comment: From the JavaScript, I see you are grabbing the first `span` you come across `.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]`, which is the tooltip initially, but becomes the error message once you have validated the form. Changing it to a `div` should probably work,  but you might find it more convenient to change it to a `label` instead.

Comment: I pretty much got it by changing the error from a span to a div and it seems to be working as I was hoping. Thanks for the insight that got the juices flowing.

Comment: I'm already using a label for the textbox so I don't think it would be appropriate to use another.